# Aliasing a nested class of a template

Tags: c++, templates, alias, inner-classes, type-alias

I have the following in a header file:

```
template <typename T>
class RingDeque {
  ...
  struct Iterator {
    using reference = T&;
    reference operator*() const;
  }
}
```

and I want to implement the `operator*()` function in the cpp file. I currently have the following in the cpp file:

```
template <typename T>
typename RingDeque<T>::Iterator::reference RingDeque<T>::Iterator::operator*()
    const {
  ... some implementation
}
```

Is there anyway I can alias a type to `RingDeque<T>::Iterator`? Perhaps something like this?

```
template <typename T>
using MyIterator = RingDeque<T>::Iterator;
template <typename T>
MyIterator::reference MyIterator::operator*()
    const {
  ... some implementation
}
```

I've tried many variations on this, and I haven't been able to substitute the types in the implementation of the method. For example, with the following code:

```
template <typename T>
using MyIterator = typename RingDeque<T>::Iterator;

template <typename T>
RingDeque<T>::Iterator::reference MyIterator::operator*() const {
  return this->_data[0];
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
ringDeque.cpp:49:1: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'RingDeque<T>::Iterator::reference'
RingDeque<T>::Iterator::reference MyIterator::operator*() const {
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
typename 
ringDeque.cpp:49:35: error: 'MyIterator' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
RingDeque<T>::Iterator::reference MyIterator::operator*() const {
                                  ^
ringDeque.cpp:46:1: note: 'MyIterator' declared here
using MyIterator = typename RingDeque<T>::Iterator;
^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: You shouldn't implement the template in the cpp file anyway. Also, please show the exact error messages you get.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: You can most certainly create an alias template to a nested type. Somehow I think this isn't what you are really asking. You want to define `operator*` without repeating most of the types twice?

Comment: Essentially, yes. See most recent edit.

Comment: @cigien These methods will have nontrivial implementation, so why should they not go to the cpp file?

Comment: See the link Fantastic Mr fox shared, and which I should have linked to in the first place, it answers that.

Comment: @Poseidon23 - Because you'll then be back here asking about linkage errors. Read the link you got from 
Fantastic Mr Fox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use a trailing return type and be done with it.

```
template <typename T>
auto RingDeque<T>::Iterator::operator*() const -> reference {
  //... some implementation
}
```

If you really want to use an alias template, then you mustn't forget it's *also*, as the name suggests, a template.

```
template <typename T>
using MyIterator = RingDeque<T>::Iterator;
template <typename T>
typename MyIterator<T>::reference RingDeque<T>::Iterator::operator*()
    const {
  //... some implementation
}
```

Comment: After adding `typename` to the template alias, I'm getting the following:

ringDeque.cpp:48:50: error: nested name specifier 'MyIterator<T>::' for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization
typename MyIterator<T>::reference MyIterator<T>::operator*() const {

Comment: @Poseidon23 - That oversight is easy enough to fix, and I have. But do not mistake SO for a free interactive debugging session by correspondence. I will only address what you post in your question, not in comments.

Comment: Got it. Why is it not possible to replace the second `RingDeque<T>::Iterator` with the template alias?

Comment: @Poseidon23 - Language rules for declaration matching. The error mentioned what the compiler expected there.